# Database - Create table with 2 fields pointing to the same table

Tags: sql, database, database-design, create-table

I need to create a table in a database that includes - the following columns -

```
table name - transaction  
time, source-address, destination-address
```

I have a table of addresses like this -

```
table name - address
address id, address, type (home/office/etc...)
```

I would like to keep only a pointer from the fields source-address and destination-address to the entries in the table "address".

Transaction can be done between the same address as well - for example it can be done from home address to home address or from home address to work address and all of it is legal.

What is the best way to do it?

```
SAMPLE DATA -  
ADDRESS  
ID    ADDR       TYPE  
1     x-street   home  
2     y-street   work  

TRANSACTION  
TIME    SRC      DST     
08:00      1     1  
08:15      2     1  
....
```

I would like to connect `TRANSACTION` table to the `ADDRESS` table but I am not sure if I can do it using foreign keys as here I have the same key - ID from the table ADDRESS which is connected to the `SRC` and `DST` fields in the table TRANSACTION.

I would appreciate to get an approach description of what is the best way to do what I need to do - like a design suggestion.

Comment: Do you know what Primary and Foreign keys are for?

Comment: Does the type field in the address table indicate if it's a source or destination?

Comment: Yes - sure I know what primary and foreign keys are for and I have a relationship based on foreign key from address table. The problem is how do I have 2 foreign keys from the same table?

Comment: No - type field in the address table is the address type - home/work/etc... It is possible that the transaction is done between the same customer from home to work address.

Comment: @Nik - Please post **sample data** and the **expected result** in some understandable form.

Comment: @Nik - It's quite OK to `JOIN` one table to another two or more times in the same query.

Comment: So, your question is how to define the 2 Foreign Keys in the `Transaction` table? (and yes, it's fine to do that.)

Answer (score 0):

Your tables seem to be fine.

The following query will allow you to get your transactions with addresses:

```
SELECT t.time, src.address "Source Address", dst.address "Destination Address"
from Transaction t
JOIN Address src ON t.src=src.id
JOIN Address dst ON t.dst=dst.id
SORT BY t.time
```